# I use gRPC to generate java code '@javax.annotation.Generated' and it reports 'Error:(20,18) java: cannot find symbol'. How to solve it？

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I use gRPC to generate code '@javax.annotation.Generated' like below picture.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then I use maven to build the project, and it reports 'Error:(20,18) java: cannot find symbol' like below picture.

[image]

How to solve it？

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can add `javax.annotation-api` dependencies to you maven `pom.xml` to resolve the annotation.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case this was caused by building the project on a system with too new version of Java accidentally installed (19 instead of 8). Changing Java version from 19 to 8 in *File -> Project Structure* fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This exactly fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I use querydsl, I meet the same similar situation in generated source.

I solved this ploblem by uncheck "Use '--release' option for cross-compilation (Java 9 and later ) in Setting "Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler"  menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem involved upgrading my Java platform (JDK8 -> JDK17) underneath the codebase (which contained Swagger codegen files).

Solution was to mass-refactor all `@javax.annotation.Generated` to `@javax.annotation.processing.Generated`. No dependency changes.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue for project https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-web-modules/spring-rest-query-language .

Issue - parent and spring-rest-query-language module have source and target as java 8. But I wanted to run this with Intellij having openjdk 21. Few other modules were working correctly with openjdk21 but this module was showing error-

`class Generated not found error, javax.annotation.processing Generate not found`

Solution -

1. I have build both parent and spring-rest-query-language with current Intellij setup i.e openjdk 21.

2.I have changed the source and target to 21 as mentioned below snapshot ( in top menu -> Intellij IDEA -> settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> java compiler).

[image]