# IntelliJ error: cannot find symbol @javax.annotation.Generated

Tags: intellij-idea

This is my first time using IntelliJ so this is probably just a basic question but alas I have it anyways.

I have cloned a github project into IntelliJ that uses gradle.  I import and first thing it says is that gradle is not set up right, so I set it up according to the following:
[gradle prefrences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mcfX.png) Java version 14.0.1.  Then it said the SDK was still not set up so I again set that up for again version even though I am not using Android.

I can successfully run a few of the grade tests but all of my java code no longer links methods and when I run the tests (directly from github without any changes yet) I get an  **error: cannot find symbol @javax.annotation.Generated(**

Also all of the methods in my [example seem to no longer link.  I have a screenshot of this too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aloDx.png)

Any guidance is appreciated, probably a problem in the set up?  I found this symbol error a few times but no resolution that helped.  I tried invalidating caches and restarting a few times. I deleted the .idea files a few times. tried a different repository in git and still having the same errors.

Thanks!

Comment: I have similar problem and solved by change settings in intellij - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75368453/3663253

Answer (score 37):

Simply add the javax annotation dependency into your `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
  //...
  implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2' 
  //...
}
```

like so.

Comment: To find the latest javax version, search in Maven Repository 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api